# Does the system stop notifying me of comments after a certain number?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

I have a couple of questions going on different sites with quite a few comments. I don't remember being notified for these. Does the systems attempt to discourage discussion in comments by stopping notifications after there are a certain number?

Comment: No. Did you check your notification bar?

Comment: No. But if it did, that would be _awesome_! Change this to a [feature-request] and I'll certainly upvote it - fair warning: most will probably downvote it.

Comment: @Yannis I would downvote that, hence, my complaint here. I wanted to be notified.